# If $X,Y$ are random variables dependent on $Z, W$, but $Z$ depends on $W$, what is the proper way to represent the entire joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that we have the following random variables $Y,X$ which are dependent on $Z, W$. However, $Z$, which is defined on a finite set $Z \in \{z_1, \ldots, z_n\}$ is further dependent on $W$. I would like to represent the joint distribution of $Y,X$. One approach (which is wrong) I thought of was to write:

$$
(Y,X) \mid Z=x \mid W \sim \mathcal{P}_{(Y,X) \mid Z \mid W}
$$

Another approach is to have:

$$
(Y,X) \mid Z=z, W \sim \mathcal{P}_{(Y,X) \mid Z, W}
$$

What is the correct way to represent the distribution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these more complex cases we usually represent them using their joint distribution as $P_{X,Y,Z,W}(x,y,z,w)=P_{X|Z,W}(x|z,w)P_{Y|Z,W}(y|z,w)P_{Z|W}(z|w)P_{W}(w)$, this gives rise to what we call a [factor graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph) representation of the joint distribution which gives nice intuition and have good properties.
On these factor graph and their use in probability you may want to check "Probability on Graphs. Random processes on graph and lattices" by Geoffrey Grimmett, chapter 7.

Comment: Thank you! Would you consider the second approach I have above, $(Y,X) \mid Z=z, W \sim \mathcal{P}_{(Y,X) \mid Z, W}$ as incorrect on any level or is it more your factorization representation is more commonly accepted?

Comment: Just to add, in your factorization, are you assuming that $X$ is conditionally independent on $Y$ given $Z, W$? I am trying to break them apart using bayes rule and do not quite get the left side of the joint distribution. thank you.

Comment: well, the approach is correct, it is just a matter of taste in the notation, your notation get limited quickly for slightly more complex models. Yes I enforced the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on $Z$ and $W$, this might not be the case but it is what I understood. It doesn't really matter, the idea is to get the strength of this kind of notations and adapt them to your problem.